# Get vertical swiper to return to slide one when the parent horizontal slider goes to next or previous slide?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Not sure where to post this (hope it's the correct place) but i thought ether way it could use some clarification.

I have a horizontal swiper (parent) and some of the slides for said swiper are vertical swipers (child) inside a horizontal slide.
I would like the (child) vertical swipers to return to the first slide when outside of the viewport for example the next or previous slide on the parent horizontal swiper.

The best example would be this swiperjs demo -
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/4c7l6v?file=/index.html

How could i make horizontal slide 2 return to vertical slide 1 when viewing horizontal slide 1 or 3?
Is there an easy function to accomplish this that i have missed?

Apologies if this has already been answered but i could not find any clear guidance while searching.

I have tried to accomplish this with a slideto function but could not get it to work.